# Codeception seeResponseMatchesJsonType method isn't validate fields correctly

Tags: json, api, codeception

I've have API test

```
public function loginAsRegisteredUser(\ApiTester $I)
{
    $I->wantTo('Login as registered user');
    $I->sendPOST('/action.php?ap=V4&p=Customer&c=Customer&a=login',['customer' => ['email' => $this->registered_user_email, 'password' => $this->registered_user_password]]);
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::OK); // 200
    $I->seeResponseIsJson();
    $I->seeResponseMatchesJsonType(["customer" => ["id_customer"=> 'string|null',"first_name"=>'string|null',"last_name"=>'string|null',"newsletter"=>'string|null']]);
}
```

and id_customer field always fails comparation

```
1) LoginCest: Login as registered user
 Test  tests/api/LoginCest.php:loginAsRegisteredUser
 Step  See response matches json type {"customer":{"id_customer":"string|null","first_name":"string|null","last_name":"string|null","newsletter":"string|null"}}
 Fail  `id_customer: 1` is of type `string|null`
```

Example of response:
{"customer":{"id_customer":1,"first_name":"as","last_name":"ewq","newsletter":"1"}}

I've tried all possible types for field id_customer(number for example), but no one works. Does anyone now solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually is validating correctly - your expectations are wrong.
Expected type is string or null, but the actual type is `integer`.